# Move the div from one location to other location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<div class="view view-discussion-block-comment view-id-discussion_block_comment view-display-id-block view-dom-id-b19735aff9214d2081003c774f83fe4a jquery-once-3-processed">
        
  
  
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
    <div id="node-425" class="node node-discussion node-teaser contextual-links-region clearfix" about="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/425" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">

    <div class="new"><div class="user-picture">
    <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" title="View user profile."><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://3pikas.ca/dev/wspengagedev2/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/image_users/picture-64-1454994015.jpg?itok=9jFn_SgV" alt="indivarsol's picture" title="indivarsol's picture"></a>  </div></div>

        <h2><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/425">New Test1</a></h2>
    <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed"><a class="contextual-links-trigger contextual-links-trigger-active" href="#">Configure</a><ul class="contextual-links"><li class="node-edit first"><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/425/edit?destination=node/303" class="colorboxNodeContextual-processed">Edit</a></li>
<li class="node-delete"><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/425/delete?destination=node/303" class="colorboxNodeContextual-processed">Delete</a></li>
<li class="node-node-export last"><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/425/node_export?destination=node/303" class="colorboxNodeContextual-processed">Node export</a></li>
</ul></div><span property="dc:title" content="New Test1" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span><span property="sioc:num_replies" content="0" datatype="xsd:integer" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
      <div class="submitted">
      <span property="dc:date dc:created" content="2016-09-21T04:58:13+00:00" datatype="xsd:dateTime" rel="sioc:has_creator">Submitted by <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" title="View user profile." class="username" xml:lang="" about="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" property="foaf:name" datatype="">indivarsol</a> on Wed, 09/21/2016 - 04:58</span>    </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-discussion-image field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://3pikas.ca/dev/wspengagedev2/sites/default/files/styles/duscussion_images/public/Lighthouse.jpg?itok=1Z1xDUZg" width="930" height="350" alt=""></div></div></div><div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><div class="readmore-summary">
  lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum <span>...<a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/Quinpool6067" class="readmore-link active">read more</a></span></div>
<div class="readmore-text" style="display:none;">
  lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts </div>
</div></div></div>  <div class="flag-outer flag-outer-support">
<span class="flag-wrapper flag-support flag-support-425">
      <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/flag/flag/support/425?destination=node/303&amp;token=3TuiMQxM-Q9mwkcZ0hoNY-x7D9ZktxP_sPjgKQRbTo0" title="Support" class="flag flag-action flag-link-toggle flag-processed" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Support</a><span class="flag-throbber">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>

  
  
<div id="comments" class="comment-wrapper">
  
  
      <h2 class="title comment-form">Submit new Idea</h2>
    <form class="comment-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/dev/wspengagedev2/comment/reply/425" method="post" id="comment-form--2" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><span class="my_class"><div id="edit-author--5" class="form-type-item form-item form-group">
  <label for="edit-author--5">  <div class="user-picture">
    <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" title="View user profile."><img typeof="Image" src="http://3pikas.ca/dev/wspengagedev2/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/image_users/picture-64-1454994015.jpg?itok=9jFn_SgV" alt="indivarsol's picture" title="indivarsol's picture"></a>  </div>
 </label>
 <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" title="View user profile." class="username" xml:lang="" about="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" property="foaf:name" datatype="">indivarsol</a>
</div>
</span><div class="field-type-text-long field-name-comment-body field-widget-text-textarea form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-comment-body--2"><div id="comment-body-add-more-wrapper--2"><div class="text-format-wrapper"><div class="form-type-textarea form-item-comment-body-und-0-value form-item form-group">
  <label for="edit-comment-body-und-0-value--2">Comment <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea class="text-full form-control ckeditor-mod form-textarea required" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-value--2" name="comment_body[und][0][value]" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
</div>
<a class="ckeditor_links" style="display:none" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:Drupal.ckeditorToggle(['edit-comment-body-und-0-value--2'],'Switch to plain text editor','Switch to rich text editor');" id="switch_edit-comment-body-und-0-value--2">Switch to plain text editor</a><fieldset class="filter-wrapper panel panel-default form-wrapper" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="filter-help form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format-help"><p><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/filter/tips" target="_blank">More information about text formats</a></p></div><div class="form-type-select form-item-comment-body-und-0-format form-item form-group">
  <label for="edit-comment-body-und-0-format--2">Text format </label>
 <select class="filter-list form-control form-select" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format--2" name="comment_body[und][0][format]"><option value="full_html" selected="selected">Full HTML</option><option value="shortcodes">Shortcodes</option><option value="plain_text">Plain text</option><option value="dynamic_shortcodes">Dynamic Shortcodes</option><option value="nd_ckeditor">CKEditor</option><option value="filtered_html">Filtered HTML</option><option value="mailchimp_campaign">MailChimp campaign</option><option value="php_code">PHP code</option><option value="html">HTML</option></select>
</div>
<div class="filter-guidelines form-wrapper form-group filter-guidelines-processed" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format-guidelines"><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-full_html" style="display: block;"><h3 style="display: none;">Full HTML</h3><ul class="tips"><li>Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-shortcodes" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">Shortcodes</h3><ul class="tips"><li><h3 style="display: none;">Shortcodes usage</h3></li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-plain_text" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">Plain text</h3><ul class="tips"><li>Lines and paragraphs break automatically.</li><li>Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-dynamic_shortcodes" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">Dynamic Shortcodes</h3></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-nd_ckeditor" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">CKEditor</h3></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-filtered_html" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">Filtered HTML</h3><ul class="tips"><li>Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.</li><li>Allowed HTML tags: &lt;a&gt; &lt;em&gt; &lt;strong&gt; &lt;cite&gt; &lt;blockquote&gt; &lt;code&gt; &lt;ul&gt; &lt;ol&gt; &lt;li&gt; &lt;dl&gt; &lt;dt&gt; &lt;dd&gt; &lt;img&gt; &lt;i&gt;&lt;p&gt;</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-mailchimp_campaign" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">MailChimp campaign</h3><ul class="tips"><li>Converts content tokens in the format <em class="placeholder">[mailchimp_campaign|entity_type=node|entity_id=1|view_mode=teaser]</em> into the appropriate rendered content and makes all paths absolute. Use the "Insert Site Content" widget below to generate tokens.</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-php_code" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">PHP code</h3><ul class="tips"><li>You may post PHP code. You should include &lt;?php ?&gt; tags.</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-html" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">HTML</h3></div></div>  </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
</div></div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-aiOWAzp15fnCmlPN7XsPslMIHbAXlS4iAm2kKCpIbNo">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="6orHSP6vWFX3QX72lMsnQOuJz9WaDS8kfyfVOTt_j-Q">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="comment_node_discussion_form">
<div class="field-type-image field-name-field-comment-images field-widget-image-image form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-field-comment-images"><div id="edit-field-comment-images-und-0-ajax-wrapper"><div class="form-type-managed-file form-item-field-comment-images-und-0 form-item form-group">
  <label for="edit-field-comment-images-und-0-upload">comment images </label>
 <div class="image-widget form-managed-file clearfix"><div class="image-widget-data"><input class="form-control form-file" type="file" id="edit-field-comment-images-und-0-upload" name="files[field_comment_images_und_0]" size="22"><button class="btn btn-default form-submit ajax-processed" id="edit-field-comment-images-und-0-upload-button" name="field_comment_images_und_0_upload_button" value="Upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
<input type="hidden" name="field_comment_images[und][0][fid]" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="field_comment_images[und][0][display]" value="1">
</div></div>
<p class="help-block">Files must be less than <strong>2 MB</strong>.<br>Allowed file types: <strong>png gif jpg jpeg</strong>.</p>
</div>
</div></div><button class="btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-submit--3" name="op" value="Publish" type="submit">Publish</button>
<div id="replace_preview_comment_node_discussion_form" class="ideal-comment-preview-area comment-preview"><div id="edit-comment-preview--2" class="form-type-item form-item form-group">
  
</div>
</div></div></form>  </div>

</div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">
    <div id="node-424" class="node node-discussion node-teaser contextual-links-region clearfix" about="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/424" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">

    <div class="new"><div class="user-picture">
    <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" title="View user profile."><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://3pikas.ca/dev/wspengagedev2/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/image_users/picture-64-1454994015.jpg?itok=9jFn_SgV" alt="indivarsol's picture" title="indivarsol's picture"></a>  </div></div>

        <h2><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/424">hello</a></h2>
    <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed"><a class="contextual-links-trigger" href="#">Configure</a><ul class="contextual-links"><li class="node-edit first"><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/424/edit?destination=node/303" class="colorboxNodeContextual-processed">Edit</a></li>
<li class="node-delete"><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/424/delete?destination=node/303" class="colorboxNodeContextual-processed">Delete</a></li>
<li class="node-node-export last"><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/node/424/node_export?destination=node/303" class="colorboxNodeContextual-processed">Node export</a></li>
</ul></div><span property="dc:title" content="hello" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span><span property="sioc:num_replies" content="0" datatype="xsd:integer" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
      <div class="submitted">
      <span property="dc:date dc:created" content="2016-09-21T04:57:01+00:00" datatype="xsd:dateTime" rel="sioc:has_creator">Submitted by <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" title="View user profile." class="username" xml:lang="" about="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" property="foaf:name" datatype="">indivarsol</a> on Wed, 09/21/2016 - 04:57</span>    </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-discussion-image field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://3pikas.ca/dev/wspengagedev2/sites/default/files/styles/duscussion_images/public/Tulips.jpg?itok=9ODUOBR1" width="930" height="350" alt=""></div></div></div><div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><div class="readmore-summary">
  lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum <span>...<a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/Quinpool6067" class="readmore-link active">read more</a></span></div>
<div class="readmore-text" style="display:none;">
  lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts lorum lipsum texts </div>
</div></div></div>  <div class="flag-outer flag-outer-support">
<span class="flag-wrapper flag-support flag-support-424">
      <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/flag/flag/support/424?destination=node/303&amp;token=fD7gJZCawlI-CGoEoWiL2ivnFT8aRMEhimVsRsYh4RA" title="Support" class="flag flag-action flag-link-toggle flag-processed" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Support</a><span class="flag-throbber">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>

  
  
<div id="comments" class="comment-wrapper">
  
  
      <h2 class="title comment-form">Submit new Idea</h2>
    <form class="comment-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/dev/wspengagedev2/comment/reply/424" method="post" id="comment-form--3" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><span class="my_class"><div id="edit-author--7" class="form-type-item form-item form-group">
  <label for="edit-author--7">  <div class="user-picture">
    <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" title="View user profile."><img typeof="Image" src="http://3pikas.ca/dev/wspengagedev2/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/image_users/picture-64-1454994015.jpg?itok=9jFn_SgV" alt="indivarsol's picture" title="indivarsol's picture"></a>  </div>
 </label>
 <a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" title="View user profile." class="username" xml:lang="" about="/dev/wspengagedev2/users/indivarsol" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" property="foaf:name" datatype="">indivarsol</a>
</div>
</span><div class="field-type-text-long field-name-comment-body field-widget-text-textarea form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-comment-body--3"><div id="comment-body-add-more-wrapper--3"><div class="text-format-wrapper"><div class="form-type-textarea form-item-comment-body-und-0-value form-item form-group">
  <label for="edit-comment-body-und-0-value--3">Comment <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea class="text-full form-control ckeditor-mod form-textarea required" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-value--3" name="comment_body[und][0][value]" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
</div>
<a class="ckeditor_links" style="display:none" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:Drupal.ckeditorToggle(['edit-comment-body-und-0-value--3'],'Switch to plain text editor','Switch to rich text editor');" id="switch_edit-comment-body-und-0-value--3">Switch to plain text editor</a><fieldset class="filter-wrapper panel panel-default form-wrapper" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format--3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="filter-help form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format-help--2"><p><a href="/dev/wspengagedev2/filter/tips" target="_blank">More information about text formats</a></p></div><div class="form-type-select form-item-comment-body-und-0-format form-item form-group">
  <label for="edit-comment-body-und-0-format--4">Text format </label>
 <select class="filter-list form-control form-select" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format--4" name="comment_body[und][0][format]"><option value="full_html" selected="selected">Full HTML</option><option value="shortcodes">Shortcodes</option><option value="plain_text">Plain text</option><option value="dynamic_shortcodes">Dynamic Shortcodes</option><option value="nd_ckeditor">CKEditor</option><option value="filtered_html">Filtered HTML</option><option value="mailchimp_campaign">MailChimp campaign</option><option value="php_code">PHP code</option><option value="html">HTML</option></select>
</div>
<div class="filter-guidelines form-wrapper form-group filter-guidelines-processed" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format-guidelines--2"><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-full_html" style="display: block;"><h3 style="display: none;">Full HTML</h3><ul class="tips"><li>Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-shortcodes" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">Shortcodes</h3><ul class="tips"><li><h3 style="display: none;">Shortcodes usage</h3></li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-plain_text" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">Plain text</h3><ul class="tips"><li>Lines and paragraphs break automatically.</li><li>Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-dynamic_shortcodes" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">Dynamic Shortcodes</h3></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-nd_ckeditor" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">CKEditor</h3></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-filtered_html" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">Filtered HTML</h3><ul class="tips"><li>Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.</li><li>Allowed HTML tags: &lt;a&gt; &lt;em&gt; &lt;strong&gt; &lt;cite&gt; &lt;blockquote&gt; &lt;code&gt; &lt;ul&gt; &lt;ol&gt; &lt;li&gt; &lt;dl&gt; &lt;dt&gt; &lt;dd&gt; &lt;img&gt; &lt;i&gt;&lt;p&gt;</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-mailchimp_campaign" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">MailChimp campaign</h3><ul class="tips"><li>Converts content tokens in the format <em class="placeholder">[mailchimp_campaign|entity_type=node|entity_id=1|view_mode=teaser]</em> into the appropriate rendered content and makes all paths absolute. Use the "Insert Site Content" widget below to generate tokens.</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-php_code" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">PHP code</h3><ul class="tips"><li>You may post PHP code. You should include &lt;?php ?&gt; tags.</li></ul></div><div class="filter-guidelines-item filter-guidelines-html" style="display: none;"><h3 style="display: none;">HTML</h3></div></div>  </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
</div></div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-W_TMyOMjvqBFOerbT8WXp5NLA3C-kKhdxttMdiVecXw">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="6orHSP6vWFX3QX72lMsnQOuJz9WaDS8kfyfVOTt_j-Q">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="comment_node_discussion_form">
<div class="field-type-image field-name-field-comment-images field-widget-image-image form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-field-comment-images--2"><div id="edit-field-comment-images-und-0--2-ajax-wrapper"><div class="form-type-managed-file form-item-field-comment-images-und-0 form-item form-group">
  <label for="edit-field-comment-images-und-0--2-upload">comment images </label>
 <div class="image-widget form-managed-file clearfix"><div class="image-widget-data"><input class="form-control form-file" type="file" id="edit-field-comment-images-und-0-upload--2" name="files[field_comment_images_und_0]" size="22"><button class="btn btn-default form-submit ajax-processed" id="edit-field-comment-images-und-0-upload-button--2" name="field_comment_images_und_0_upload_button" value="Upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
<input type="hidden" name="field_comment_images[und][0][fid]" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="field_comment_images[und][0][display]" value="1">
</div></div>
<p class="help-block">Files must be less than <strong>2 MB</strong>.<br>Allowed file types: <strong>png gif jpg jpeg</strong>.</p>
</div>
</div></div><button class="btn btn-default form-submit" id="edit-submit--4" name="op" value="Publish" type="submit">Publish</button>
<div id="replace_preview_comment_node_discussion_form" class="ideal-comment-preview-area comment-preview"><div id="edit-comment-preview--3" class="form-type-item form-item form-group">
  
</div>
</div></div></form>  </div>

</div>
  </div>
    </div>
  
  
</div>
```

I want to move the div to another page. It has been move to but the not with their respective inherit div. Please help to resolve this problem.
I am using this jquery

```
jQuery(" .views-row .node-discussion .new .user-picture ").insertBefore(
    jQuery( " .node-discussion.node-teaser .field-name-body" ) 
);
```

[image]

I want `<div class="user-picture">` insertBefore the `<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">` with every node.

Comment: please can you provide little more code or fiddle

Comment: Karuna, please add your HTML code here.

Comment: you can't move a div from a page to another with javascript.you may hack it with ajax but not with simple dom manipulation

Comment: i want to move the div according to each node.

Comment: i want  <div class="user-picture"> insertBefore <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">

Comment: Your question is still unclear. For instance, what do you mean by "It has been move to but the not with their respective inherit div"? At first I thought there were some invisible html tags in your text, but there weren't. (Not in that sentence anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

tldr but..

```
$d = $("#someDiv");
$c = $d.clone(); // make a copy
$d.remove(); // remove the original
$("#newLocation").append($c); //insert to new location
```